# Jumps into "Success" Before URL Call Finishes on Safari?

Tags: jquery, ajax

We are experiencing some weird behavior when making jquery ajax calls (jquery version 1.8.3) inside Safari browser (mac and windows) where the onSuccess portion of the call executes before the actual url call finishes. We see the calls being returned when we pull up Developer tools with a 200 status, but since the code execution jumps right into onSuccess, the data does not get a chance to render. We don't experience any of this with IE, Chrome, Firefox. We've found that if you step through/debug the code, that it never happens. Only happens when we are running it in a release mode. We think it has something to do with the async call, but can't obviously verify that. The calls are returning with a 204 status code. Any suggestions/insight would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

```
//private methods
function callService(url, verb, args, version, successCallback, errorCallback, publishMethodName) {

    $.ajax({
        url: url
        , type: verb
        , data: args
           , accepts: { json: "application/json;V=" + version + ";Persist=" + cfn.core.services.persist + ", text/javascript" }
        , contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8" // content type sent to server
        , dataType: "json" //Expected data format from server
        , processdata: true
        , success: function (result) {
            if(successCallback != null)
                successCallback(result, publishMethodName);
          }
        , error: function (xhr) {
            if (errorCallback == null)
                serviceFailed(xhr, window.location.href, url, verb, version, publishMethodName);
            else {
                serviceFailed(xhr, window.location.href, url, verb, version, publishMethodName);
                errorCallback(xhr);
            }
        }
    });
} //callService
```